# Can I Modify MSBuild Compilation Options to Prevent / Ignore Specific Build Errors?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, continuous-integration

I'm attempting to set up a Continuous Integration process for a legacy VB.Net ASP.Net Forms application, using an on premises TFS 2017 build agent. However, MSBuild fails to build the project (which builds happily in VS).

The build fails with the multiple alerts for the following error types.

> Error BC32025: '#Region' and '#End Region' statements are not valid
>   within method bodies/multiline lambdas.

and

> Error BC30126: 'ReadOnly' property must provide a 'Get'.

I understand why these errors are thrown, but I'd rather not have to plough through the entire project refactoring this working code just to get it to work with the MSBuild compiler, when it compiles and runs perfectly well in Visual Studio.

Is there a switch / setting I can use to tell MSBuild to ignore these / other errors? I briefly tried using the `/p:nowarn` flag in the MSBuild Arguments field, but the build then just seemed to fail without telling me about it....

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's your version of .NET installed on the build server. I'd check what version you have local, and what version you have on the build server and reconcile.

You might want to try the /toolsversion:x.x switch (/tv:x.x for short) for MSBuild, and pick from 2.0, 3.5, and 4.0.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference

Comment: Thanks for the input Jim. I've got .net 4.7 installed on my development PC, and the build server only has 4.6.1 on it (due to having an issue installing Windows updates at present), so maybe that is at the root of the problem. I've tried using a variety of different toolversions `/tv:14.0, /tv:4.0, /tv:3.5`, without any success.

Comment: Let me know how it goes. I'm willing to bet that 4.7 will fix your issue.

Comment: Just to get things going for now, I waded into the code to make all the changes MSBuild wanted, and as it turned out, there weren't that many (I feared wave after wave of errors would be unearthed as I fixed each one), but I do want to get to the bottom of this, for future reference (and to allow us to use #region tags inside methods again!), so I'll absolutely let you know how it goes...